# Angular form cross-validation error message does not display in view unless another error is triggered

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to compare password and his confirmation in an angular reactive form.

**FormGroup :**

```
this.registerForm = new FormGroup(
  {
    ...
    password: new FormControl(this.user.password, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(8),
      patternValidator(/\d/, { hasNumber: true }),
      patternValidator(/[A-Z]/, { hasCapitalCase: true }),
      patternValidator(/[a-z]/, { hasSmallCase: true }),
    ]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl(),
    ...
  },
  { validators: passwordMatchValidator }
);
```

**passwordMatchValidator :**

```
export const passwordMatchValidator: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] = (
  control: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const password = control.get('password');
  const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword');
  console.log(
    password && confirmPassword && password.value !== confirmPassword.value
  );
  return password && confirmPassword && password.value !== confirmPassword.value
    ? { hasPasswordsMatch: true }
    : null;
};
```

**View :**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Mot de passe</mat-label>
    <input
      [type]="passwordHide ? 'password' : 'text'"
      matInput
      formControlName="password"
    />
    <button
      type="button"
      mat-icon-button
      matSuffix
      (click)="passwordHide = !passwordHide"
      [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
      [attr.aria-pressed]="passwordHide"
    >
      <mat-icon>{{
        passwordHide ? "visibility_off" : "visibility"
      }}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.required">
      Le mot de passe est obligatoire.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.hasCapitalCase">
      Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins une majuscule.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.hasSmallCase">
      Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins une minuscule.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.hasNumber">
      Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins un chiffre.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.minlength">
      Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 caractères.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.errors?.hasPasswordsMatch && confirmPassword.touched">
      Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I followed angular tutorial https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms.
But I can't display the error unless I another password's error is already displayed.
[image: Demo]

You can see in the GIF that on page loading, the log from passwordMatchValidator returns false and it returns true when I fill the first input.

It should show the mat-error tag at this point but it doesn't and I don't know why.
If I delete the uppercase character, it shows both uppercase and password match errors messages.

Why ?? Can someone help me on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your first part of the question only:**
You are checking for password mismatch in your validator function passwordMatchValidator, the name hasPasswordsMatch is the problem here which confuses

```
password.value !== confirmPassword.value
```

so initially when your type password in the first input element it returns as false as there is a mismatch with the confirm password field and goes away after entering the same password in the confirm password field